# Computers with windows 7 does not see each other on network when users are without password

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm trying to connect several computer with Windows 7 on a network.
On each pc , there's a user with the same name and without password.
But in this case the computers does not see each other on network.
When I configure the same password for all users , then all the things are ok , the computers can see each other , can use shared folder and shared printers.

Is there any possibility do do these without setting a password ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This is a ***REALLY BAD IDEA***.

What you're looking for is in Group Policy

Use GPedit.msc and go to 
Computer configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options.

Look for "Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only" and set to disabled.

The policy referenced configures the following registry value:

Registry Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
Registry Path: \System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa

Value Name: LimitBlankPasswordUse

Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1